# Enchanting Items

Tags: diablo-iii, xbox-360

I have asked this question on a few sites but haven't really gotten a direct response. I've read in a few places that you can "enchant" items using the enchantress. Not only can I not do it - I don't even see how I would. I have my Demon Hunter @ level 60+ (paragon 2) and she is @ level 60. I have leveled up the blacksmith and jeweler to 10 and have taught each of them numerous recipes. I've gotten access to Unicorn land too but am totally lost with this enchanting thing.

Second Point - The Infernal Machine Event.the thing you build using keys - can that be done on the Xbox 360 or not? I haven't come across any keys, I'm just past 65% with the completed challenges so.

Lastly - Like with the enchanting I have seen people talk about being able to access a Greed Demon realm via the Treasure 'Pygmys' (etc.) portals. Some people say its once you get to level 60, others say 70.

And again - I have the Xbox 360 game.

Can someone please clear these issues up for me?

Comment: Hello an welcome to Arqade. I see you have several questions, we like to encourage people to create 1 "thread" per question so if you have more than one issue it's better to open several question. Even though they relate to the same game.

Answer (score 4):

The character who is enchanting items is the **Mystic**, not the Enchantress. Enchantress is a follower, and a Mystic is the third Artisan, available in the Reaper of Souls expansion.

Realm of Treasure goblins can be opened at level 70 in **Adventure mode**, which is only available in Reaper of Souls.

The Infernal Machine keys must be obtained from Keywardens on certain difficulties. To find Keywardens, and to check difficulty requirements, consult one of the many guides, like this one: http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/The_Infernal_Machine

Only the Infernal Machine is available to you in the base Diablo 3, for everything else you need to buy the expansion (known as the **Ultimate Evil Edition** on consoles).

Comment: Bleh, I almost never solo anymore and got the two names mixed up.  Good answer.

Comment: You should note that the Mystic is available only with the expansion.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau You mean I should write something like "_Mystic is the third Artisan, available in the Reaper of Souls expansion_", right? Something like the second line of my answer?

Comment: Thanks man that explains why i couldn't get at this stuff....i only have the base game. I sorta feel like a dummy but i went back and looked over where i saw these bits of info and i swear it doesn't specify that you need to have the expansion!!!!!!!! Thanks again

Comment: @Joeball No problem. Blizzard is intentionally making people buy the expansion, of course. By the way, now that your problem is solved, please tick one of our answers you like the most as "accepted" (see checkmark on the left), so that other people could see that the thread is useful.

Answer (score 3):

1. Level 60 Paragon 2 probably means you don't have the expansion, Reaper of Souls, which is why you can't find the Mystic.  She's in the expansion content, which also raises the max level to 70.
2. *[Orc JMR's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/209521/24592) says that you can get the Infernal Machine keys on the console version, and includes a link that goes into detail.*
3. Occasionally, when you kill a Treasure Goblin while you are in Adventure Mode but NOT in a Rift, it will open the Treasure Rift, which is what you're talking about here.  I don't think level matters, but I'd suggest being max level anyway, just to amke sure if the ring drops it's level is maxed.  Adventure mode is also Reaper of Souls content.

(In the future, it's usually best to ask each question separately.  That way people who don't know the answer to one, like me, can still answer what they do know without having to risk being downvoted for providing a partial answer.  Also, it makes it easier for other people with the same questions to find the answers when they search - if you search for your question #3 on this site, you'll find it's already been answered - which is why the site asks us to do it that way.)

Comment: OKay cool beans. This was my first question so i still new to this site but i'll get the protocol down rikki-tik. Thanks for the help!